# Paygate Recurring payment in php

Tags: php, payment, recurring

I am setting up a Recurring payment option on a client site. the payment is for the donation using Paygate "PaySub"(paysubscription) method "https://developer.paygate.co.za/product/13" the code for sending payment requrest work fine. but their code have no clue about the notify_url  on which the payment site send a notification to the subscriber site on each recurring due date. How will i keep track of each recurring that happen on its due date.
The code for the setting up the recurring payment is mention here.

```
<form action="https://www.paygate.co.za/paysubs/process.trans" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="21">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYGATE_ID" value="10011013800">
<input type="hidden" name="REFERENCE" value="Customer1">
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="3299">
<input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="ZAR">
<input type="hidden" name="RETURN_URL" value="http://localhost">
<input type="hidden" name="TRANSACTION_DATE" value="2015-12-06 18:30">
<input type="hidden" name="SUBS_START_DATE" value="2015-12-06">
<input type="hidden" name="SUBS_END_DATE" value="2016-12-06">
<input type="hidden" name="SUBS_FREQUENCY" value="111">
<input type="hidden" name="PROCESS_NOW" value="NO">
<input type="hidden" name="PROCESS_NOW_AMOUNT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUM" value="f672dfced5732fd4c8dc58e2a4c6ce78">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The return url only is for returning from the payment site to subscriber site and its work fine. but the issue is that how i will know the status of each single payment that has been pay through recurring. i means if a recurring payment is set for 1 year then how will i know that on each month the payment is payed.

Comment: so check the api if there is some method

Comment: The api has all the code i mention above. i have even send email to  "info@paygate.co.za" and " support@paygate.co.za " but they did not answer yet. Thanks for reviewing on my post..

Comment: if not better create an issue on they github repository https://github.com/PayGate/PayWeb3